# Showing Fragment from Fragment Dialog

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-alertdialog

In my code, I'm trying to show Fragment in some case of FragmentDialog, but nothing happens.
Here is my code:

```
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle bundle) {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
    builder.setTitle(getString(R.string.trip_type_title));
    builder.setItems(
            new String[]{
                    getString(R.string.option1),
                    getString(R.string.option2),
                    getString(R.string.cancel)
            },
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
                    switch (item) {
                        case 0:
                            break;
                        case 1:
                            FragmentManager manager = getFragmentManager();
                            FragmentTransaction transaction = manager.beginTransaction();

                            Fragment fragment = new SomeFragment();

                            transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
                            transaction.addToBackStack(null);

                            break;
                        case 2:
                            break;
                    }
                }
            });


    AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();

    return dialog;
}
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to commit your changes:

```
transaction.replace(R.id.content, fragment);
transaction.addToBackStack(null);
transaction.commit();
```